# How can i use taglib in JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, maven, taglib

I know this problem has been posted many times but every solutions that have been posted didn't solve my problem whereas my issue is the same.
I have a JSP page and i want to use taglib in. So i added this line in it :

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

My project runs with maven 2 so i included in pom.xml that dependency too :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is the line which in the web.xml :

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee `enter code here`http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
```

And now, here is the error i Get whatever i try :

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: L'uri absolute: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in the file web.xml or in the others files jar deployed with this application

---

When I build the project, there is still nothing in web-inf/lib...
Am I doing something wrong ? I mean, once i have the configuration i put in my last post, i do on my project a "maven build", it displays on my screen "build success", then i launch tomcat and enter the url of my asp and it prints the error i gave above...

Here is my entire pom.xml given that you told me somethind could go wrong with it:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>CapG</groupId>
<artifactId>CapG</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: What matters is if the jstl jar file is part of the deployed war file (or exploded war), under WEB-INF/lib. Make sure that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get your packaged `war` file through maven verify that you have the required `jstl-1.2.jar` in your `WEB-INF/lib` directory. If not, perhaps something needs to be fixed in your `pom.xml`.

**EDIT**: Try adding `<packaging>war</packaging>` (before build) in your pom.xml.

Comment: The dependency i added aaas copied from maven repository on internet so i didn't think i would be wrong

Comment: @user1655512 You're correct. There are several different groupIds available for jstl jars.